# post back data rendered by json to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-partialview

How to post back data rendered by json back to controller action. For example if I rendered  data(using partial views) like below. What are the different ways to post the rendered data back to controller?

```
 $(function() {
    var form = $("#mainForm");
    $('#someButton').click( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/PostbackGrid/StudentDetail',
            data:form.serialize() ,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#partial').html(data);
        },

    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing data back and forth between the UI and the controller I would instead use JSON as message format, instead of html.

Comment: But the UI is complex. It is a table with dropdownlist. The table is editable grid where row can be added in the client. what would you suggest for this?